# NumPy - assigning to views returned by function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) N-D array `a` and a function `f(a)` which returns any complex view `v` of `a`, also array `b` which has same shape as `v`.

What is the easiest way to assign `b` to `v`? Both of them can be multi-dimensional.

Simplest trial like in next code to assign to function's return value fails with error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`:

```
import numpy as np
a, b = np.arange(10), np.arange(2)
a[2:4] = b # Working
f = lambda a: a[2:4] # Returns any view of a
f(a) = b # Not working, syntax error
```

By the task it is not allowed to pass array `b` argument to function `f`, function itself should be un-modified.

Comment: `x[...] = ....` triggers a `setitem` method call.  -

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! Created [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64193235/941531) out of it.

Comment: Actually I meant the kind of action discussed in my answer.  I meant `x[some_indexing]=some_values`, not using `Ellipsis` literally.   Still in your answer, using `Ellipsis` instead of `slice(None)` is a bit more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@hpaulj [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192040/numpy-assigning-to-views-returned-by-function?noredirect=1#comment113514398_64192040) next solution that works for any dimensionality (unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64192041/941531) solution):

```
f(a)[...] = b
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer. You should consider removing the other.

Comment: @MadPhysicist What's incorrect with the other one? Any answer can be allowed as soon as it is a different way of solving or almost solving the task for most cases. At least I'll accept this one for sure later. There are thousands of questions on StackOverflow that list dozens of different solutions for same task, and only because there are better solutions these donzens of answers are not removed. At least I think solution from the other answer is probably used by most newbies in NumPy most of the time.

Comment: It doesn't work for 0D arrays. I removed the down vote since you noted that

Comment: @MadPhysicist You're correct, that solution doesn't cover 100% of use cases, but still many StackOverflow answers don't cover all corner cases and they usually mention these uncovered cases like I did in my other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out myself one simplest solution, it works correctly for any N-D case except for 0-dimensional arrays (scalars):

```
f(a)[:] = b
```

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to find a solution, make sure you understand the problem.

```
In [27]: a, b = np.arange(10), np.arange(2)
In [28]: f = lambda a: a[2:4]
In [29]: f(a)
Out[29]: array([2, 3])
In [30]: f(a) = b
  File "<ipython-input-30-df88b52b4d3c>", line 1
    f(a) = b
            ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

This error is a fundamental Python one.  A matter of syntax.

But look at what happens when we using indexing.

The slicing you do in `f` is:

```
In [31]: a[2:4]
Out[31]: array([2, 3])
In [32]: a.__getitem__(slice(2,4))
Out[32]: array([2, 3])
```

The desired assignment slicing is:

```
In [33]: a[2:4] = b
In [34]: a.__setitem__(slice(2,4),b)
In [35]: a
Out[35]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Note that `setitem` takes `b` as an argument.  `a.__setitem__(slice(2,4))=b` would run into that same syntax error.

This use of `setitem` allows us to use advanced indexing (a list):

```
In [38]: a[[0,2]] = b
In [39]: a.__setitem__([0,2],b)
```

Where as this does not work:

```
In [40]: a[[0,2]][...] = b
```

because it is actually `a.__getitem__([0,2]).__setitem__(Ellipsis,b)`.  The set modifies the copy produced by the get.  This chaining only works when the first index produces a `view`.

Comment: Is something wrong with two of my answers? They both produce correct results, underlying array `a` is modified correctly. Or you just wanted to explain in details what is happening underneath?

Comment: In my question I was specifically emphasising that my function always returns a writable view.

Comment: Maybe there is some function in numpy to somehow `assert` that returned from function thing is actually a view of array `a`, not a copy?